# I need to setup RIAK cluster in Ec2 instances which is CentOS

Tags: erlang, amazon-ec2, riak

When I install the latest version of erlang R14B04 in EC2 I get an error stating

```
Fatal error in wait__(): Function not implemented (38)
```

So When I installed the lower version of Erlang which is R13B03 It got installed in it.
But i couldnt install the RIAK 1.x version in it.

Could anyone please help me in this to set up riak cluster on ec2

Comment: i guess you need help from Riak Community/ Riak Mailing List: http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com

Answer (score 1):

If you search the stack overflow archives, you will learn that certain CentOS versions doesn't work with R14Bx. You are probably being hit by this problem here. Installing a newer version of CentOS that fixes the problem is probably a good solution.